# Representations of semidirect product over $C_p$

Tags: finite-groups, modular-representation-theory

Hi,
I am wondering if anything is known about irreducible representations of a semidirect product over $C_p:=\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ in general or at least in special cases. For example of $C_q \rtimes C_l$ over $C_p$, where $p,q,l$ are some primes. Is there any well-known literature?

Thank you for hints!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at Weintraub "Representation theory ... " for Mackey Machine (pg 120 or so).

Edit in response to [Mackey Maschine for semidirect product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104087/mackey-maschine-for-semidirect-product). The reference does not give a solution to the problem, but studying the Mackey machine/Clifford theory seems like the right starting point for a semidirect product.

Comment: For finite groups this is known as Clifford theory.